# Uncaught ReferenceError: lsj_C4msOic is not defined at HTMLButtonElement.onclick

Tags: javascript, html

I am getting data from an API in javascript then dynamically creating buttons based on that like so:

```
 document.getElementsByClassName("videos")[0].innerHTML += '<img src="' + video.snippet.thumbnails.default.url + '"> <h5>' + video.snippet.title +'<button  onclick="Advertise('+video.id.videoId +')" class="button is-primary"> Advertise</button> </h5>'
```

When the button is clicked, I want it to pass the id that is has to the advertise function. However, when I click the button this error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: lsj_C4msOic is not defined at HTMLButtonElement.onclick
```

Can someone help me out?

Comment: You need to put quotes around it, otherwise it tries to treat it as a variable.  Your string delimiter is a single quote, so you are not putting any quotes around it

Comment: Oh, I feel dumb. Can you put this as an answer so I can mark it as so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add quotes around it like this:

```js
document.getElementsByClassName("videos")[0].innerHTML += '<img src="' + video.snippet.thumbnails.default.url + '"> <h5>' + video.snippet.title +'<button  onclick="Advertise(\''+video.id.videoId +'\')" class="button is-primary"> Advertise</button> </h5>'
```

If you don't have quotes around it, the browser assumes it's a variable and tries to treat it like one, thereby generating a [`ReferenceError`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/ReferenceError).

This is what the `onclick` attribute looks like without the quotes:

```js
Advertise(lsj_C4msOic)
```

With the quotes:

```js
Advertise('lsj_C4msOic')
```